# Monorepo with Lerna & Next.JS not working : Module not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, monorepo, lerna

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to setup a monorepo with `lerna` & `nextjs` and have been following a tutorial but [get stuck at this point.](https://buttercms.com/blog/nextjs-storybook-and-lerna-build-a-monorepo-structure#connectingfrontandcomponents)

My file structure looks exactly as specified in the tutorial:

```
lerna.json
package.json
packages
  --- components (React Components)
    --- package.json
    --- ...
  --- frontend (NEXTJS APP)
    --- package.json
    --- ...
```

It worked fine so far, but now when I try to import `components` in my frontend nextjs application, it gives me a `Module not found` Error:

> ./pages/index.js:4:0
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'components'

My package.json in the `/` (root) folder:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

package.json in `packages/frontend` (NextJS App) :

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "components": "0.0.0",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2"
  }
}
```

package.json in the `/packages/components` folder:

```
{
  "name": "components",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "> TODO: description",
  "author": "Anton",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "__tests__"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: run tests from root\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "microbundle watch --jsx React.createElement"
  },
  "source": "lib/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.13.3"
  }
}
```

I have been following the linked tutorial pretty much to the dot, I'm really not sure what's going on here, but then again, I am a beginner/low intermediate and would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue following the tutorial [here](https://buttercms.com/blog/nextjs-storybook-and-lerna-build-a-monorepo-structure).
The gotcha was that you have to run `lerna bootstrap` again from the root of the monorepo. For me this fixed it.